# Python DataFrame calculate cost of sales

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 4 table tables for purchase, return purchase, sales, and return sales

- I made merge for all in one data frame
- I made sort by item_Id,date,transaction type (purchase,return purchase,return sales,sales)
  the result is

| date | item_Id | Type | qty | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-12-24 | 2 | Purchase | 5 | 10 |
| 2023-12-24 | 2 | sales | 1 | 50 |
| 2023-12-25 | 2 | return purchase | 1 | 10 |
| 2023-12-26 | 2 | Purchase | 10 | 11 |
| 2023-12-27 | 2 | return purchase | 5 | 11 |
| 2023-12-28 | 2 | sales | 5 | 40 |
| 2023-12-20 | 3 | Purchase | 100 | 10 |
| 2023-12-21 | 3 | return purchase | 10 | 1 |
| 2023-12-22 | 3 | sales | 20 | 100 |
| 2023-12-23 | 3 | return sales | 5 | 100 |

DataFrame

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2023-12-24','2023-12-24','2023-12-25','2023-12-26','2023-12-27','2023-12-28','2023-12-20','2023-12-21','2023-12-22','2023-12-23'],'item_Id': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],'Type': ['Purchase','sales','return purchase','Purchase','return purchase','sales','Purchase','return purchase','sales','return sales'],'qty': [5, 1, 1, 10, 5, 5, 100, 10, 20, 5],'price': [10, 50, 10, 11, 11, 40, 10, 15, 100, 100]})
```

I get qty balance using this code

```
df['BalanceQty'] = df['qty'].where((df['Type']=='Purchase') | (df['Type']=='return sales'),  df['qty'] * -1).groupby(df['item_Id']).cumsum()
```

**My Problem is I need to calculate average Cost balance for every transaction group by Item_Id I try this code but shift() work with old value not new**

```
df['Cost']  = np.where((df['Type']=='Purchase'),  df.qty  * df.price, np.where((df['Type']=='return purchase'),df.qty  * df.price *-1,0))      
df['BalanceCost'] = 0
df['BalanceCost'] = np.where((df['Type']=='Purchase') | (df['Type']=='return purchase'), df['BalanceCost'].shift(1) + df['Cost'], df['BalanceCost'].shift(1)/df['BalanceQty'].shift(1) * df['BalanceQty'])
```

So I need to calculate the balance cost and unit cost for every transaction

the final result is

| date | item_Id | Type | qty | price | Qty Balance | cost | balanceCost | unit Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-12-24 | 2 | Purchase | 5 | 10 | 5 | 50 | 50.000000 | 10.000000 |
| 2023-12-24 | 2 | sales | 1 | 50 | 4 | 0 | 40.000000 | 10.000000 |
| 2023-12-25 | 2 | return purchase | 1 | 10 | 3 | -10 | 30.000000 | 10.000000 |
| 2023-12-26 | 2 | Purchase | 10 | 11 | 13 | 110 | 140.000000 | 10.769231 |
| 2023-12-27 | 2 | return purchase | 5 | 11 | 8 | -55 | 85.000000 | 10.625000 |
| 2023-12-28 | 2 | sales | 5 | 40 | 3 | 0 | 31.875000 | 10.625000 |
| 2023-12-20 | 3 | Purchase | 100 | 10 | 100 | 1000 | 1000.000000 | 10.000000 |
| 2023-12-21 | 3 | return purchase | 10 | 15 | 90 | -150 | 850.000000 | 9.444444 |
| 2023-12-22 | 3 | sales | 20 | 100 | 70 | 0 | 661.111111 | 9.444444 |
| 2023-12-23 | 3 | return sales | 5 | 100 | 65 | 0 | 613.888889 | 9.444444 |

Equation is

- for balanceCost

  - IF Purchase or return purchase get previous balanceCost + cost
  - else get previous balanceCost /previous  Qty Balance  * current Qty Balance
- for unit Cost = balanceCost / Qty Balance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way of achieving this with vectorized operations.

If your dataframe isn't too large, you can use the following approach, iterating over the rows so the changes in `balanceCost` can be properly propagated depending on the value of `Type`:

```
df["BalanceQty"] = (
    df["qty"]
    .where(df["Type"].isin(["Purchase", "return sales"]), df["qty"] * -1)
    .groupby(df["item_Id"])
    .cumsum()
)

df["Cost"] = np.where(
    (df["Type"] == "Purchase"),
    df.qty * df.price,
    np.where((df["Type"] == "return purchase"), df.qty * df.price * -1, 0),
)

df["BalanceCost"] = 0

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if i == 0 or df.at[i - 1, "item_Id"] != row["item_Id"]:
        df.at[i, "BalanceCost"] = row["Cost"]
    elif row["Type"] in ["Purchase", "return purchase"]:
        df.at[i, "BalanceCost"] = df.at[i - 1, "BalanceCost"] + row["Cost"]
    else:
        df.at[i, "BalanceCost"] = (
            df.at[i - 1, "BalanceCost"] / df.at[i - 1, "BalanceQty"] * row["BalanceQty"]
        )

df["UnitCost"] = df["BalanceCost"] / df["BalanceQty"]
```

```
         date  item_Id             Type  qty  price  BalanceQty  Cost  BalanceCost   UnitCost
0  2023-12-24        2         Purchase    5     10           5    50    50.000000  10.000000
1  2023-12-24        2            sales    1     50           4     0    40.000000  10.000000
2  2023-12-25        2  return purchase    1     10           3   -10    30.000000  10.000000
3  2023-12-26        2         Purchase   10     11          13   110   140.000000  10.769231
4  2023-12-27        2  return purchase    5     11           8   -55    85.000000  10.625000
5  2023-12-28        2            sales    5     40           3     0    31.875000  10.625000
6  2023-12-20        3         Purchase  100     10         100  1000  1000.000000  10.000000
7  2023-12-21        3  return purchase   10     15          90  -150   850.000000   9.444444
8  2023-12-22        3            sales   20    100          70     0   661.111111   9.444444
9  2023-12-23        3     return sales    5    100          75     0   708.333333   9.444444
```

Comment: thank you e-motta
I also arrived at the same solution with a slight difference
It is a 100% correct solution, but is there better and less code?

Comment: @MustafaShazLy Given that the value of `BalanceQty` depends on previous values but the way it's calculated changes depending on the value of `Type`, I can't see a way of making this vectorized. For an iterative approach, this is about as efficient as it'll be.